# Are the interrupts in Linux queued

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86, linux-device-driver, interrupt

I wrote a sample driver which disables keyboard interrupt for few seconds, and when i press keys at that duration, i get the pressed keys on the console when the interrupt is enabled?

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/irqflags.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>

unsigned int irq = 1;

module_param(irq, int, 0);

static int __init my_init(void)
{
    pr_info("module is loaded on processor:%d\n", smp_processor_id());
    pr_info("Disabling Interrupt:%u\n", irq);
    disable_irq(irq);
    pr_info("Disabled Interrupt:%u\n", irq);
    mdelay(10000L);
    pr_info("Enabling Interrupt:%u\n", irq);
    enable_irq(irq);
    pr_info("Enabled Interrupt:%u\n", irq);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit my_exit(void)
{
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_exit);
```

Comment: Several key presses are held in the keyboard controller until software reads them. If you press more  than a few keys while the interrupt is disabled, some will be lost. I think the limit is something like 8 or 16.

Comment: Also one pending interrupt is held in the interrupt controller and is delivered when interrupts are reenabled. When the interrupt is received, software reads all the queued key presses, not just the first one.

Comment: disable_irq(irq); disables interrupt on all processors

Comment: @prl: You should write that as an answer...

Comment: Can anyone confirm me the size of the queue, because i see more than 16 keys are being read after enabling the keyboard interrupt

Comment: @caf,, it's not really a very good answer because I was thinking of the 8042 keyboard controller, but he's undoubtedly using a USB keyboard. (Which is probably why he's seeing more than 16 keys buffered.) (I'll still see if I can come up with a correct answer.)

Comment: I have never read anywhere about 8042 keyboard controller having a buffer, most of the information is about reading the io port to get the data

Comment: Are you sure that IRQ 1 is used for the keyboard when you have a USB keyboard?

Comment: I am using my in built keyboard of laptop

Comment: I was mistaken about buffering in the keyboard controller. When the keyboard controller receives a scan code from the keyboard, it signals the keyboard to not send any more scan codes until software has read the output buffer. So any buffering is in the keyboard itself.

Comment: @prl, but for USB it's theoretically possible (Disclaim: I didn't read HID protocol specifications) that keyboard sends entire buffer as USB bulk transfer.